# Python: Conditional to stop the execution of a script

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that accesses the vertex groups of a mesh object. I want the script to stop executing under certain conditions, like if the active object is not a mesh, or if it has no vertex groups.

I tried `import sys` paired with `sys.exit(0)` but that closes Blender.

I tried `quit()` but that crashed Blender.

How can I build stopping safeguards into my code? Thanks.

For reference, here is my code so far (which crashes Blender):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene 

act_obj = context.active_object # get active object

# make sure active object is a mesh
print('Active object\'s type is: ' + act_obj.type)
if act_obj.type is not "MESH":
    print('Active object\'s type is not MESH. Aborting.')
    quit()

# make sure the mesh has vertex groups
if not act_obj.vertex_groups[0]:
    print('Active object has no vertex groups. Aborting')
    quit()

v_grps = act_obj.vertex_groups
print(v_grps[0])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115584/discussion-on-question-by-mentalist-python-conditional-to-stop-the-execution-of).