# What is the Bash "exit 0" equivalent in blender python or how to stop script execution?

Tags: python

Is there a way to terminate a script in *Blender* python that is somewhat equivalent to the [`Bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) [`exit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/exit.1p.html) command? I found [this article](https://appdividend.com/2021/03/31/how-to-stop-python-script-from-execution/) but the suggestions did not work for *Blender* python. I also found the thread [Python: Conditional to stop the execution of a script [closed]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200052/python-conditional-to-stop-the-execution-of-a-script) but there was nothing discussed about stopping the script execution. I've tried the `exit()`, `quit()`, `sys.exit()`, and `os._exit(0)` functions but they behave like `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()` and close the entire *Blender* application. The `exit` (without parenthesis) command does nothing. I sometimes need to do some testing and have to get the script to terminate at some point in the execution and adding a simple one-liner *terminate* code would be really convenient.

In bash I would just have to call exit

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "do some stuff"
exit 0
echo "don't execute stuff after exit coz i'm still testing the stuff above"
```

But in *Blender* python how do I do this?

```
print("do some stuff")
exit # exit(), sys.exit(), bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
print("don't execute stuff after exit coz i'm still testing the stuff above")
```

I don't like the inconvenient string `'''` usage for pseudo-comments because it requires me to add 2 lines of `'''` instead of a one-liner *exit/terminate* command.

**EDIT**:

I found a useful workaround that doesn't require me to touch the closing pair of the `'''` since it is commented out at the bottom and only becomes active if i insert `'''` that would represent the *pseudo-"exit"* statement.

```
print("do some stuff")
''' # i can add/remove this without needing to touch the closing pair
print("don't execute stuff after exit coz i'm still testing the stuff above")
#'''
```

Comment: If you just want to skip code for testing purposes you also could create a function and use the `return` statement to jump out at a certain line.

Comment: yeah that's another possible workaround. i like the comment trick though. looks like there is no "exit" in python blender.

Comment: There is an exit, but, as you found out, it does what Python spec says it should do and completely exists the program. That is, by the way, how bash exit works as well, except bash forks a subprocess and waits for it to exit.  I don't recommend using subprocesses for this sort of debugging.  FWIW, I just paste  segments of code into the Python window when I'm doing this sort of debugging, but @Blunder suggestion is a good one if you don't want the hassle of pasting.

Comment: @MartyFouts yes that is correct. i like the comment trick though its much better coz that way i dont have to indent the code.

Comment: @MartyFouts can you write your comment as answer to this post that includes the workarounds using a `function` and using also the `'''` triple single quote methodology i demonstrated? i'll pick your post as answer to close this question :)

Comment: Sure. As soon as I get back to my desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [Harry McKenzie](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/142292/harry-mckenzie)'s request I've created this answer from comments on the question.

I pointed out:

> There is an exit, but, as you found out, it does what Python spec says it should do and completely exists the program. That is, by the way, how bash exit works as well, except bash forks a subprocess and waits for it to exit.

and mentioned

> I just paste segments of code into the Python window when I'm doing this sort of debugging.

[Blunder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/107598/blunder) suggested one useful workaround:

> If you just want to skip code for testing purposes you also could create a function and use the return statement to jump out at a certain line.

Harry McKenzie described a way to effectively "comment out" code. It's a two step process:

1. Place the line `#'''` (a comment hash-tag (octothorpe) followed by three single quotes) as the last line of the script.  If there is no matching set of three single quotes earlier, it will be treated by the parser as a comment and ignored.
2. "comment out" starting with the first line you don't want executed by adding `''' #` (three single quotes followed by a comment hash-tag (octothorpe) at the start of that line.

This works by overloading the doc-string convention.  Blender treats everything between the first three single quotes and the last three as one long string that it reserves as a documentation string.

Note that there is one small issue with this approach.  If there is an actual doc string in the "commented out" region, it will cause an error.  Consider this contrived script:

```py
print("run this")
print("ignore this")
'''
this is a real doc string
'''
print("ignore this")
```

Now consider wanting to only run the first line.  Using the doc-string trick gives this code

```py
print("run this")
''' #print("ignore this")
'''
this is a real doc string
'''
print("ignore this")
#'''
```

but that has resulted in the real doc string being outside the string and running this will give a syntax error at line 4.

Comment: excellent! thank you!